# Activate tracking for ArcGIS Online with python

Tags: arcgis-online, xml, update, service-definition

It is possible to update data in ArcGIS Online by python-script:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/01/24/updating-your-hosted-feature-service-for-10-2/

Configuration is done by changing the sddraft, which is structured as a tree. In the draft there is no 'editorTrackingInfo'-element as well as no subelements. So they have to be added. I tried this by doing:

```
a=ET.SubElement( prop, “editorTrackingInfo” )    
b1=ET.SubElement(a, “enableEditorTracking” )    
b1.text=”true”
```

As a result the XML is extended:

```
<PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
<Key>WebCapabilities</Key>
   <Value xsi:type="xs:string">Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing,Extract,Sync</Value>
   <editorTrackingInfo>
     <enableEditorTracking>true</enableEditorTracking>
                <enableOwnershipAccessControl>true</enableOwnershipAccessControl>
                <allowOthersToUpdate>true</allowOthersToUpdate>
                <allowOthersToDelete>true</allowOthersToDelete>
   </editorTrackingInfo>
</PropertySetProperty>
```

I upload the Service Definition. Unfortunately in ArcGIS Online the tracking is not activated. Could you help?